# How do I use quasi-quotations to get an AST in Nemerle?

Tags: macros, metaprogramming, abstract-syntax-tree, quotations, nemerle

I try to get the AST of a simple code-snippet in Nemerle, using Nemerle's quasi-quotes.

This is the code I tried:

```
def ast() : void {
  System.Console.WriteLine(<["Test"]>)
}
```

I ran it on [IdeOne](http://ideone.com/On7Yq) (ncc 0.9.3) and I got this error:

```
prog.nem:2:30:2:36: error: unbound name `Literal.String'
prog.nem:2:30:2:36: error: unbound name `PExpr.Literal'
```

How can I solve these issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add *Nemerle.Compiler.dll* as a reference to your project. Also, some of the more complex quasi-quotes will only work in macros.

```
using Nemerle.Compiler;
using System.Console;

macro Test()
{
    def x = <[ while (true) WriteLine(4) ]>.ToString();
    <[ WriteLine($x) ]>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Quasi-quotations are intended for use in macros. They need a context of a compiler. Create a macro library project, and use a quasi-quotations in it.